# Return array of all matches between two ranges

Tags: excel

Ok so I am trying to take a common tutorial array formula a step further but cannot figure out how.

Essentially I have a set of sheets with values like below:

```
| Sheet 1                       || Sheet 2              |
| Products(1)   | Product Group || Products(2)   | Data |
|               |               ||               |      |
| 100           | 1             || 100           | abc  |
| 200           | 2             || 200           | def  |
| 300           | 3             || 200           | ghi  |
| 400           | 3             || 500           | jkl  |
| 500           | 2             || 400           | mno  |
```

Sheet 1 lists all parameters that classify each product and uses those to assign each product to a group. Essentially Products is a unique index key.

Sheet 2 is a tracking list of every time that a product is run, how it did. Therefore product numbers may show up multiple times or not at all.

I have a third sheet in which a product number is entered, from that its group number is calculated, and sheet 1 is searched for all products with that group number and the list is returned using an array formula (using this tutorial http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/ which shows up all over on line by different people). We will call this "Column K" on Sheet 3.

What I want to do now is take it a step further and return "Data" from Sheet 2 for all matches between "Sheet 2"!"Products(2)" and "Sheet 3"!"Column K". If "Column K" was fixed I could use the same formula again and put an OR statement into the IF expression, but because K is dynamically populated I am not sure how to find them all.

For clarification, The end result that I would ideally show is like this:

```
| Sheet 3                                                 |
| Product Num   | Column K    | Column L    | Column M    |
| (user enters) | (automatic) | (automatic) | (automatic) |
| 500           | 200         | 200         | def         |
|               | 500         | 200         | ghi         |
| Product Group |             | 500         | jkl         |
| (automatic)   |             |             |             |
| 2             |             |             |             |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare a column vector with an row vector in an array formula then it will compare each value from the column with each value in the row. So the following will work because we transpose the values in `Sheet3!K1:K[n]` into a row vector before comparing with `Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000`.

Sheet1:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:
[image: Sheet2]

Sheet3:
[image: Sheet3]

Formulas in `Sheet3`:

In `A5`:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

In `K2` downwards:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10000=$A$5,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10000)),ROW(1:1))),"")}
```

In `L2` downwards:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000=TRANSPOSE($K$1:INDEX($K:$K,MAX(IF($K$1:$K$10000<>"",ROW($K$1:$K$10000))))),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000)),ROW(1:1)))}
```

In `M2` downwards:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000=TRANSPOSE($K$1:INDEX($K:$K,MAX(IF($K$1:$K$10000<>"",ROW($K$1:$K$10000))))),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000)),ROW(1:1)))}
```

Formulas in `K2`,`L2`,`M2` are array formulas. Input them without the curly brackets and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

The reference to `K[n]` in `Sheet3!K1:K[n]` is computed with

```
INDEX($K:$K,MAX(IF($K$1:$K$10000<>"",ROW($K$1:$K$10000))))
```

therein the

```
MAX(IF($K$1:$K$10000<>"",ROW($K$1:$K$10000)))
```

gets the largest row number in column K where the content not equals "".

---

If the product numbers are ever numeric, then it is easier and it will be possible to have the results sorted also.

Sheet1 and sheet2 see above.

Sheet3:
[image: Sheet3]

Formulas in Sheet3:

In `A5`: see above

In `K2` downwards:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10000=$A$5,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10000),ROW(1:1)),"")}
```

In `L2` downwards:

```
{=SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10000=TRANSPOSE($K$2:INDEX($K:$K,MATCH(MAX($K:$K),$K:$K))),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10000),ROW(1:1))}
```

In `M2` downwards:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000=$L2,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000)),COUNTIF($L$2:$L2,L2)))}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! Didn't know about the dot product type of comparison arrays in excel have for comparisons